# SQLServerで複数のCSVファイルからテーブルを作成しインポートしたい

Tags: csv, sql-server

SQLServerのインポートウィザードにてCSVファイルからテーブルを作成することができます。
ただし、これは１ファイルずつの処理になるため複数ファイルある場合は非常に手間がかかります。
これを、１回の手順で複数のファイルに対して実行することはできないでしょうか？
CSVファイルのファイル名をテーブル名に、ヘッダをカラム名にしたいです。

以前、クエリにてこれを実現しているURLを見つけたのですが現在見つからなくなってしまいました。
もしそのURLや実現方法をご存知の方がいましたら教えてください

Comment: 参考: [Import Multiple CSV Files to SQL Server from a Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16076309/2322778)

Comment: ありがとうございます！これで出来ました！

Comment: 忘備録：
CSVにより改行コードが\nのものと\r\nのものが混在しているとエラーになったためpowershellにて一括変換を行いました
ls | foreach{ (cat $_) -join "`r`n" | set-content $_ }